# ATI Radeon 2400 no colors

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon

I just got the ATI Radeon 2400 on Windows 7 and there are no colors showing ! only blue (I guess) and black.

What can be the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try completely uninstalling the ATI Drivers. If you go to your Start Menu, then right click "Computer", you can select "Manage". Once inside, find Device Manager and expand the category that says "Display Adapters". Right click it and hit uninstall. When the dialog box comes up asking if you're sure, select the option to delete the device drivers. Proceed with that.

From there you'll notice your screen resolution will go way down. If this fixes the color issues, then attempt to re-install your drivers. Use an old version if you have to. If this does not fix the color issue, it could very well be a hardware problem. Most likely the video card or the monitor. Test the monitor first by borrowing one from another computer. If that monitor still gives the color issues, you might try replacing your video card.

Comment: I did what you asked me to do and the colors didn't appear.

Comment: If I use my built in GPU card,I get the colors without a problem.

Comment: When you say the colors didn't appear, did you mean it's working correctly or it's continuing to not work? Also, what step that I recommended did you take? Let me know and I can try to help you further.

Comment: It's continuing not to work. what I did was uninstalling the driver

Comment: You say when you use the built-in graphics card that the colors show up fine? If that's the case, it's most likely the graphics card and not the monitor. If uninstalling the driver didn't fix it, try replacing the card. If it's under warranty, you will probably get it replaced for free.

Comment: Not under warranty. :\ I got it from a friend and it was working totally fine for him! might be the motherboard ?

Comment: Do you have another slot to put the graphics card in? It could be a faulty slot. Could also be it got damaged in the time that he took it out of his machine and you put it in your machine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4191/discussion-between-wadie-and-erickj92)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your cables are plugged in all the way. When using VGA cables, if it is not plugged in all the way, it can cause discoloration like you're experiencing. If your plugs are in completely, you may want to try a different cord. If all of the pins are not connected, it will cause the issue.

Sometimes the VGA ports on the graphics card are a ribbon and then go down and plug into the graphics card. If you're using a port like that, you will want to make sure that the ribbon is also fully plugged into the graphics card.

Do you have another monitor that you can test it with? If your monitor has faulty wiring, it could also cause the issue.

Comment: I'm sure the monitor isn't the issue. all the pins are connected too!
I am using VGA port.